# A feedback rating calculator which weighs more on the positive ratings.

Tags: algorithms

An algorithm which rates a product on a few parameters and then shows the average rating. The rating calculator should put more weight on the positive ratings.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new here. I am working on a project which gives a product score out of 10 for a product, but the problem is that people tend to give only negative ratings. So I need to create a project where we give more weight on the positive ratings while creating a score. I prefer to seperate the negative and the positive ratings and then compute their average by giving more weight on the positive ratings

Comment: I see .. Aff thrdr informations to your question . It's more clear.

Comment: Scoring algorithms that are actually useful in real life are non-trivial. Just google for "online shop scoring algorithm" and you will even find papers on it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is that if, for example, people are $20$ times more likely to give a "1" rating than a "10" rating *to similar products*, then each "10" rating should weigh as much as $20$ "1" ratings.

So you keep track of the values $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_{10}$ where each $n_k$ is the total number of $k$ ratings given on all products in the same class. And let $p_k$ be the number of $k$ ratings for a particular product. Then the average rating for that product would be
$$P_\text{avg} = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{10} \dfrac{p_k}{n_k}k}{\sum_{k=1}^{10} \dfrac{p_k}{n_k}}$$

This is simplistic, so it probably falls short of ComFreek's "actually useful in real life" criterion. It certainly can be easily exploited by faked positive reviews. If you are wanting to build a real useful website, then I echo ComFreek's suggestion that you need to review the existing literature. A thread on MSE is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank You, appreciate that.